# How to return every position of letters from a string of letters every time they occur using the zip and length functions?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function `search :: String -> Char -> [Int]` that returns the positions of
all occurrences of the second argument in the first. For example:

```
search "Bookshop" 'o' == [1,2,6]
search "senselessness" 's' == [0,3,7,8,11,12]
```

How can one use the function `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`, the function `length :: [a] -> Int`, and the term forms `[m..n]` and `[m..]` in a list comprehension to do this?

I am writing a code for this, and (correct me if I'm wrong) since the output is not binary as a zip one should, the string one should be omitted from the list comprehension and a parallel list comprehension should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call `length`. There rarely is, if ever.

```
search :: (Num b, Eq a, Enum b) => [a] -> a -> [b]
search s char = [ i | (i,c) <- zip [0..] s, c==char]
```

Testing:

```
> search "senselessness" 's'
[0,3,7,8,11,12]
```

As you can see, we draw both `i` and `c` from the zipped list, use `c` in comparison and output `i` if the test passes.

Comment: oh wow, but I somewhat don't understand this code. I have several questions:

what does the (Num b, Eq a, Enum b) => [a] do?
what does the guard c==char do? 
why does the s have to be separated from the zip [0..]?

thank you!

edit: oh sorry was just being a dumbass i know now what c==char does

Comment: `(Num b, Eq a, Enum b) => [a] -> a -> [b]` is just a general way to write the type of this function, but we can make it more specific as `[Char] -> [Integer]` which is the same as `String -> Integer`. the `(Num b, Eq a, Enum b) =>` part, specifically, is known as a "type constraint". `Num`, `Eq`, `Enum` are known as "type classes". ----- `char` is the second argument to the function, and `c` is each character from the string, in turn. so the guard `c==char` tests whether the two are equal, just as you wanted. so when it's True, we're interested in this `c`, and its position `i`.

Comment: and that position we get from the zipped string: try `zip [0..] "abcde"` and see what this function call produces. (as you can see, `s` is not "separated", it is a second argument in that function call, the call to `zip`, where the first argument is `[0..]` the increasing list of indices from 0; and the second argument is the string, the argument to the function `search`.

Comment: ohhh i see now!

when i run the zip[0..] "abcde" , it produces a type match error focusing on the char at the back, but why does it do that? because i was under the impression that the char behind has no connection to the s in front

Comment: no, I mean just run it at the prompt. `zip[0..] "abcde"` produces a list of pairs... of what? try it. separately.

Comment: it produces a list of pairs of numbers and letters, ohhh i know now. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237798/discussion-between-idontknowhowtocode-and-will-ness).